# How to create Custom properties on lineItems

Tags: metadata, custom-properties, virtocommerce

I have researched a bit and found that it is possible to create custom properties on for example a product. These can be accessed through the property `Properties` on a product of type `VirtoCommerceCatalogModuleWebModelProduct`.

But on a `lineitem` of type `VirtoCommerceCartModuleWebModelLineItem` I cant find any property called `Properties`. Furthermore I cant find a place to create properties on `lineitems` in the backend.

So my question is:
Is it possible to create some metadata, like custom properties on lineitems?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive api available for managing properties. That is described here: http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Using+dynamic+properties.

If you want to create custom properties using backend admin, go to configuration and then select "dynamic properties". You should see lineitem object there and will be able to add additional ones.

Comment: Okay thanks! :) but when installing the nuget package found here https://www.nuget.org/packages/VirtoCommerce.Client/ i cant use the  namespace VirtoCommerce.Platform.Core.DynamicProperties; It is the .Platform that cant be found. Any idea why? :)

Comment: Sorted it out, Thanks!